# How many points determine a two variable polynomial of degree n+k?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I am working with sequences and it would be extraordinarily useful to have a two variable version of the following:

A degree-$n$ polynomial is uniquely characterized by its values at any $n+1$ distinct points.

The polynomial $p(x)$of degree $n$ is determined completely up to a constant factor, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, by exactly $n$ roots. Any other point of $p(x)$ would determine this constant factor. Because of the aforementioned theorem in practice we may not need $d+1$ distinct points, repeated roots would simplify things.

I would like to know the answer to the following question(I restrict the question to two-variable polynomials, I am not interested in the general case):

Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$ and $k$ in $y$. The Degree of $P(x,y)$ being $n+k$. How many points will uniquely determine any such polynomial?

Any references to books, theorems, articles, papers are welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$ and $k$ in $y$ has $(n+1)(k+1)$ coefficients, and these will determined by the values at $(n+1)(k+1)$ points in "general position".  But you can't just take any $(n+1)(k+1)$ distinct points.  For example, if your points
happen to be on a curve $Q(x,y) = 0$, they can't distinguish between multiples of $Q(x,y)$.

Comment: How do we prove that $(n+1)(k+1)$ points in general position gives the same number of linearly independent equations in the coefficients when our space is of much smaller dimension?

Comment: It suffices for the Jacobian matrix of the map from coefficients to values at the points to be nonsingular.  The determinant of that matrix is a polynomial with integer coefficients in the point coordinates.  Use induction to show that the leading principal minors are generically nonzero.